# Local hosting python azure function fail with M1

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, apple-m1

As title, I want to host azure function in local with VSCode but something error.

- Python version 3.9.12 (python3).
- Azure Functions Core Tools

  - Core Tools Version:       4.0.4483 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
  - Function Runtime Version: 4.1.3.17473

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

local.setting.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": ""
  }
}
```

Error Message:

```
Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
....
[2022-05-09T06:52:10.300Z]     from . import dispatcher
[2022-05-09T06:52:10.300Z]   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4483/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 19, in <module>
[2022-05-09T06:52:10.300Z]     import grpc
[2022-05-09T06:52:10.300Z]   File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4483/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/grpc/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
[2022-05-09T06:52:10.300Z]     from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
[2022-05-09T06:52:10.300Z] ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4483/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4483/workers/python/3.9/OSX/X64/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/cygrpc.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)
[2022-05-09T06:52:13.512Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000008F1C7F2E'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing from our end we observed that If you have an arm64 Python, it'll never be able to load an x86_64 shared library hence we need to enable Rosetta which works at a process by process level.

**Steps to be followed**

1. Check the Rosetta in iTerm.
2. Install homebrew, azure functions core tools, and python in the current homebrew.
3. And then run your azure function.

**REFERENCES:**
[Support running on M1 Macs [Python]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/915)

Answer (score 0):

### Setting up Rosetta

1. Open Finder, go to Applications and find Terminal.
2. Right-click the new terminal (iTerm), and choose "Get Info."
3. Enable "Open using Rosetta" for the new terminal.
4. Run `arch` in the terminal, you should see `i386` as the response.

### Installing Tools

After setting up x86 emulation, install the necessary tools:

1. Install Homebrew:

   ```bash
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install Python using Homebrew:
   `/usr/local/bin/brew install python@3.9`
3. Install Azure Functions Core Tools:

   ```bash
   /usr/local/bin/brew tap azure/functions
   /usr/local/bin/brew install azure-functions-core-tools@4
   ```

### Usage

Since you have another installation of azure-functions-core-tools, you need to specify which version you want to use. (You can create alias for that)

```bash
/usr/local/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4915/func host start
```

More detailed instruction in [Running python azure function locally on an M1 M2 macOS ~ Issam Ben](http://issamben.com/running-python-azure-function-locally-on-an-m1-m2/)